# How to display different front-end router view at the same time using Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I have a page, there are three iframes in this page(I have to use iframe) and they will be displayed at the same time. In these iframes, I set specified the url comes from a SPA page. such as:

```
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'air',
      component: () => import('@/views/dashboard/index.vue'),
      children: [
        {
          path: '/top',
          name: 'airTop',
          component: () => import('@/views/dashboard/top.vue')
        },
        {
          path: '/left',
          name: 'airLeft',
          component: () => import('@/views/dashboard/left.vue')
        },
        {
          path: '/right',
          name: 'airRight',
          component: () => import('@/views/dashboard/right.vue')
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

[image]
When I change some values in top iframe, I find the left one and the right one will not be changed. I realize that the different iframe will get a new Vue instance, so the value won't be shared.
**My question**: Is there any way can share the value in different iframe at the same time. Using sington?

Comment: You are right. Since you are loading the same app, but in different iframes, you will get 3 different Vue instance. My suggestion would be to let the iframes emit the current route it is in and let the local app control the location of the other iframes.

Comment: @CENT1PEDE Could you give me more detail, please？

Comment: It seems like these iFrames will be hosted on the same site, correct? If so, you could leverage postMessage events. This would allow the left/right iFrames to listen for a postMessage event emitted from the top iFrame which would accept a value, execute a function based on that value, which could update the store and in return update the computed value for the left/right iFrames. MDN postMessage page for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: @CENT1PEDE Thanks for your patiently reply. These iframes are indeed on the same site. That's a good inspiration to watch postMessage and update the store in current pages!